# Uninstall only installed files NSIS

Tags: nsis

I want to find a way to uninstall only installed files.
I tried http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files but I have around 10.000 files nested in many directories, therefore specifying each file separately in a nsis script is not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `!system` command to execute external tools at compile-time. This external tool/script should generate include files with install and uninstall instructions.

You can also use NSIS on the fly to generate the instructions but it is a bit messy when you put all of it in a single script:

```
; Generate some files for this example:
!system 'mkdir "$%temp%\testdir\subdir\sub2\sub3"'
!appendfile "$%temp%\testdir\file1.txt" ""
!appendfile "$%temp%\testdir\subdir\file2.txt" ""
!appendfile "$%temp%\testdir\subdir\sub2\file3.txt" ""
!appendfile "$%temp%\testdir\subdir\sub2\sub3\file4.txt" ""



!macro GENFILELIST_Enum SourceDir InstDir
Push "${SourceDir}"
Push "${InstDir}"
Call GENFILELIST_Enum
!macroend

### Start editing here ###

!macro GeneratePages
OutFile "test.exe"
Name "Test"
RequestExecutionLevel admin
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyTestApp"

Page Directory
Page InstFiles
UninstPage UninstConfirm
UninstPage InstFiles
!macroend

!macro GENFILELIST
!insertmacro GENFILELIST_Enum "$%temp%\testdir" "" ; Files to install
!macroend

!macro GenerateInstallSections FileInstructions
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
!include "${FileInstructions}"
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
SectionEnd
!macroend

!macro GenerateUninstallSections FileInstructions
Section Uninstall
SetOutPath $InstDir
!include "${FileInstructions}"
SetOutPath $Temp
Delete "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
RmDir $InstDir
SectionEnd
!macroend

### Stop editing here ###


!ifndef GENFILELIST_IN
!tempfile GENFILELISTAPP
!tempfile GENFILELIST_IN
!tempfile GENFILELIST_UN
!appendfile "${GENFILELIST_IN}" '!define GENFILELIST_UN "${GENFILELIST_UN}"$\n'
!appendfile "${GENFILELIST_IN}" 'OutFile "${GENFILELISTAPP}"$\n'
!system '"${NSISDIR}/makensis" "/DGENFILELIST_IN=${GENFILELIST_IN}" "${__FILE__}"' = 0
!system '"${GENFILELISTAPP}" /S' = 0
!delfile "${GENFILELISTAPP}"
!insertmacro GeneratePages
!insertmacro GenerateInstallSections "${GENFILELIST_IN}"
!insertmacro GenerateUninstallSections "${GENFILELIST_UN}"
!delfile "${GENFILELIST_IN}"
!delfile "${GENFILELIST_UN}"
!else
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include "${GENFILELIST_IN}"
!delfile "${GENFILELIST_IN}"
!macro GENFILELIST_Append file string tmpvar
FileOpen ${tmpvar} "${file}" a
FileSeek ${tmpvar} 0 END
FileWrite ${tmpvar} '${string}'
FileClose ${tmpvar}
!macroend
!define DOLLAR "$$"
Function GENFILELIST_Enum
System::Store S
Pop $9 ; Relative path
Pop $8 ; Base path
${IfThen} $9 == "" ${|} StrCpy $9 "${DOLLAR}OutDir" ${|}
FindFirst $0 $1 "$8\*"
loop:
StrCmp $1 "" stop
    StrCmp $1 "." next
    StrCmp $1 ".." next
    StrCpy $3 $1
    ${If} ${FileExists} "$8\$1\*"
        !insertmacro GENFILELIST_Append "${GENFILELIST_IN}" 'SetOutPath "${DOLLAR}OutDir\$1"$\n' $2
        Push $8\$1
        Push $9\$1
        Call GENFILELIST_Enum
    ${Else}
        !insertmacro GENFILELIST_Append "${GENFILELIST_IN}" 'File "$8\$1"$\n' $2
        !insertmacro GENFILELIST_Append "${GENFILELIST_UN}" 'Delete "$9\$1"$\n' $2
    ${EndIf}
    next:
    FindNext $0 $1
    Goto loop
stop:
FindClose $0
!insertmacro GENFILELIST_Append "${GENFILELIST_UN}" 'RmDir "$9"$\n' $2
System::Store L
FunctionEnd
RequestExecutionLevel user
Section
!insertmacro GENFILELIST
SectionEnd
!endif
```

Comment: so the result is pretty much the same as it was for the script I mentioned above.